# Python 2.6 regular expression mechanisms?

Tags: python, regex

I am learning regular expression and I would like to check the mechanisms that python is using.

I have the regex:

```
s = re.findall(ur"\d+\.?\d+", "123,45.567 78").
```

First I thought that the result was going to be only 45.567

When I run it, I got all the numbers including the decimal (["123", "45.567", "78"]) but it is not very clear the process that is used.

Here is my understanding: 
Python starts first with the expression \d+ that will find 123 that is ok (greedy search as much as possible before the comma). Next it expects an optional dot (.?) that is not there and it is ok. Next, it expects one or more digits. But the next char is a comma (,) that is not accepted. Python will back to 12 (drop 3). 12 fullfils the first \d+. Next it expects an optional dot that is not there and next it expects one or more digits and 3 matches it. That is, 123 fullfils the whole regex.

Will Python memorize the offset 2 for 123 and start all over again after 123. That is, will Python start using the whole regex at the string 45.567,78.

That is, the whole regex is used thre times. The first time it finds 123.
The second time it finds 45.567 and the third time it will find 78.

Comment: Please pay more attention to the formatting of your questions. Big blocks of text are hard to read. And use code formatting.

Comment: Running `s = re.findall(ur"\d+\.?\d+", "123,45.567 78", re.DEBUG)` should help you follow Python's behavior.

Comment: Your description of how the first `123` is matched is correct. After this is matched the regex engine attempts to match at the position immediately following the first match, (the position right before the comma), and this fails. But the engine does not give up - it _"bumps along"_ to the next char in the string and is able to match the `45.567`. It then fails and bumps-along again just before the space, then finds the third match. The regex engine will bump along checking for a match at every position within the string, even at the position following the last char in the string.

Answer (score 4):

`\d+\.?\d+` will always also match `\d+\d+` since the `.` is optional (maybe you now see why it matches all). So it can backtrack as much as the constraints allow.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation of findall](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) (emphasis mine):

> Return all **non-overlapping** matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

It seems to me this would describe the behaviour you're seeing. To get non-overlapping matches, you have to start the next match after the end of the previous one.